# Arduino Bluetooth BLE boards function as iBeacon emitters, or receivers?

Tags: arduino, bluetooth-low-energy

I have just purchased the estimate iBeacon developer kit and am doing research on iBeacons, building demo apps using Adobe AIR with native extensions.

I was curious if any of the many Bluetooth BLE boards can function as iBeacon emitters, or receivers.

[BLE shield 1](http://redbearlab.com/bleshield/)
[BLE shield 2](http://www.seeedstudio.com/depot/Bluetooth-40-Low-Energy-BLE-Shield-p-1255.html)

Comment: With the exception of a few BLE chips that can function in the peripheral role only (ie, be a beacon but not a beacon detector, while most can do either) this basically comes down to if someone (maybe you?) has written the necessary software yet.

Answer (score 1):

Readbearlab has [code](https://github.com/RedBearLab/MiniBeacon) for their BLEMini board to turn it into an iBeacon. According to their website they are evaluating porting it to the BLE shields.